# @() inside an always block

Tags: verilog

Whether using @() inside an always block is a bad practice or in other words it is wrong? The example code is given below:

```
always@(negedge clk)begin

        @(valueI)begin
            deterministicEnable=0;
            iterate=iterate+1;
            deterministicEnable=1;
            j=0;
            $display("%h  %d   %d",valueI,$time,j);
        end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong for synthesisable code. It's not wrong for your testbench.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use it. At least you would see that something is wrong if the TB is stuck... 
What would be the proper implementation for a wait statement in a TB?

Comment: @Patrick I guess you could implement a timeout with a `fork`...`join_any`. Or you could use VHDL which has that feature built in... I'll get my coat.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed by most RTL synthesis tools.

It's a bad practice in general. You have code that is synchronous to a falling edge of a clock. Then you wait for another change that may or may not be coincident with the previous clock. I don't know if that is important in your case.

Also, the assignment to `deterministicEnable` is a glitch that may or may not be visible to other processes.